# BigQuery - How to get table schema from C# client library?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to load the schema using C# library?  I found a post on Python that people can call table.reload() to actually load the schema. But I don't find any similar functionality in C# library.

```
BigQueryClient bqClient = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
var ds = bqClient.GetDataset(dataset);
var tableList = ds.ListTables();

foreach (var table in ds.ListTables())
{
    //here I need table schema to work on, but schema is null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
BigQueryClient bqClient = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
var ds = bqClient.GetDataset(dataset);
var tableList = ds.ListTables();

foreach (var table in ds.ListTables())
{
    //here I need table schema to work on, but schema is null
    BigQueryTable table = bqClient.GetTable(datasetId, tableId);
    TableSchema schema = table.Schema;
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.Snippets/BigQueryClientSnippets.cs#L374) and [here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryTable.html#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryTable_Schema).